# VSTO Excel Interop ListObject.AddEx (2010+) to ListObject.Add (2003) Conversion

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, vsto, listobject

As part of an Excel helper utility I'm developing I'm moving large commonly used Excel spreadsheets to MS SQL for performance as well as data validation via SSIS packages further down the line.

As part of this I wrote a basic Database Connection Class that mimics the Data --> From Other Sources --> From SQL Server button. I got this working at home using a copy of Office 2013, and I anticipated some conversion issues, primarily where the Excel Interop API has changed and upgrading to Office 2010 or above is not an option. My main problem seems to be conversion of the newer command AddEx:

`MyListObjects.AddEx(ExcelAPI.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcQuery, MyConnection, Type.Missing, ExcelAPI.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes,StartRange);`

To the 2003/2007 version Add as per MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.listobjects.add(v=office.11).aspx)

//2007 command//

```
  ExcelAPI.ListObject CurrentTable = MyListObjects.Add(ExcelAPI.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcExternal, MyConnection,Type.Missing,ExcelAPI.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes,StartRange);
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

My initial thought was changes in the ExcelAPI.XlYesNoGuess enumeration, so I tried manually values, but I then encountered compiler errors. I've tried removing the parameters one at a time using `Type.Missing` to trace the culprit however this seems to have caused more errors than it solved despite MSDN stating these are all optional.

The connection string made up like this:

```
String FullString = "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source= " + PCNameOrIP + @"\" + InstanceName + @";Initial Catalog=" + DatabaseName + @";User ID=" + DatabaseUserName + @";Password=" + DatabasePassword;
```

Method test call parameters:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.DM.EstablishConnection("BREWL14H58107", "SQLEXPRESS", "TestDB", "sa", "Password0", "SELECT * FROM TestDB.dbo.Test", "Demo File", "Testing");
```

Having done looked into this some more. It seems the code I have works fine from home, the amended Add. However from work I am still getting:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```